# How do I fire four bullets in four directions (0°, 90°, 180°, 270°)?

Tags: gml, game-maker-studio-2

I'm following this [game tutorial for GameMaker Studio 2](https://youtu.be/ZLEEf0c8EHY?t=666) by FriendlyCosmonaut which sacrifices readability for better understanding which I don't mind really, but I'm stuck at the four bullets part of the video. I just don't get it.

So it basically iterates and multiplies i by 90 which gives the desired angle to a lengthdir_x & lengthdir_y function that returns the needed component to initialize the bullet in the right direction.

It's been working fine for the other cases (two_bullets, three_bullets) but it doesn't work for the four_bullets & star_bullets part of the tutorial.

### **The only way I got it to seem like it's working is by iterating 5 times instead of 4. It looks exactly like what I need but it shouldn't work, in my opinion.**

Here's the file I think I have an issue at (case powerups.four_bullets & case powerups.star_bullets):

```
///@description create_bullet
///@arg direction
///@arg speed
///@arg faction
///@arg gun_type*

var _dir = argument[0];
var _spd = argument[1];
var _fac = argument[2];

var _gun_type = -1;
if(argument_count > 3) _gun_type = argument[3];

switch(_gun_type){
    case powerups.two_bullets:
        var _sep = 12;

        var inst = instance_create_layer(
                    x+ lengthdir_x(_sep, _dir+90),
                    y+lengthdir_y(_sep, _dir+90),
                    "Instances", obj_bullet
                    );
        initialize_bullet(_dir, _spd, _fac, inst)
    
        var inst = instance_create_layer(
                    x + lengthdir_x(_sep, _dir-90),
                    y+lengthdir_y(_sep, _dir-90),
                    "Instances", obj_bullet
                    );
        initialize_bullet(_dir, _spd, _fac, inst)
        break;
    
    case powerups.three_bullets:
        var inst = instance_create_layer(
                    x,
                    y,
                    "Instances", obj_bullet
                    );
        initialize_bullet(_dir, _spd, _fac, inst)
    
        var _sep = 12;

        var inst = instance_create_layer(
                    x + lengthdir_x(_sep, _dir+90),
                    y + lengthdir_y(_sep, _dir+90),
                    "Instances", obj_bullet
                    );
        initialize_bullet(_dir, _spd, _fac, inst)
    
        var inst = instance_create_layer(
                    x + lengthdir_x(_sep, _dir-90),
                    y + lengthdir_y(_sep, _dir-90),
                    "Instances", obj_bullet
                    );
        initialize_bullet(_dir, _spd, _fac, inst)
        break;
    
    case powerups.four_bullets:
        var _sep = 7;
        var bullet_angle;

        var i = 0; repeat(4){
            bullet_angle = _dir + (i * 90);

            show_debug_message("bullet_angle:" + string(bullet_angle));
            show_debug_message("_dir:" + string(_dir));
            show_debug_message("i:" + string(i));
        
            var inst = instance_create_layer(
                    x + lengthdir_x(_sep, bullet_angle),
                    y + lengthdir_y(_sep, bullet_angle),
                    "Instances", obj_bullet
                    );
            initialize_bullet(bullet_angle, _spd, _fac, inst)
            i++;
        }
        break;
    
    case powerups.star_bullets:
        var _sep = 7;
        var bullet_angle;

        var i = 0; repeat(8){
            bullet_angle = _dir + (i*45);
            var inst = instance_create_layer(
                    x+ lengthdir_x(_sep, bullet_angle),
                    y+lengthdir_y(_sep, bullet_angle),
                     "Instances", obj_bullet
                    );
            initialize_bullet(bullet_angle, _spd, _fac, inst)
            i++;
        }
        break;
    
    case powerups.laser_bullets:
    
        break;
    default:
        var inst = instance_create_layer(x,y, "Instances", obj_bullet);
        initialize_bullet(_dir, _spd, _fac, inst)
        break;
}

inst.direction = image_angle;
```

These images are with 4 iterations, not 5.

Screenshot with bullets flying away from ship origin. But the bullet that should go 270° is going to 0° instead, or so it seems.

[image: Screenshot with bullets flying away from ship origin. But the bullet that should go 270° is going to 0° instead, or so it seems.]

Console output

[image: Console output]

Answer (score 1):

`Repeat()` is a function I'm not familiar with, but it does look like it has similair
behavior as a for loop though.
I thought first that it didn't included the max number, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Keep in mind that you can debug the program by setting a breakpoint in this block of code, that way you can see how the code behave and notice if there's an unintentional behavior around. The reason why it shoots a second bullet to the right might be because it reaches the `default` statement in your switch case.

Comment: Yeah I thought that too about the default statement but I checked and it doesn't reach it. I'll keep looking. Thanks though for giving me pointers!

Answer (score 1):

Everything in this script appears to be good (I even ran some in my own demo GameMaker project). This is also backed up by the debug log you provided. When you use `repeat(4)`, it is passing in the correct values into `initialize_bullet()`. In your example it was 0, 90, 180, 270 (the same values seen in your debug log). This would lead me to think there might be something weird going on further down the line, such as inside of your script `initialize_bullet()`. That's my best guess as to what is giving you issues. I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, so here are a few other possible sources of the issues I can think of:

- Something in `obj_bullet` (or even in another object) is modifying the angle of `obj_bullet`.
- The `_spd` variable being passed into `initialize_bullet()` is incorrect.
- The speed of `obj_bullet` gets modified in some other way.